# Android audio player

Tags: java, android, event-handling, audio

I want to implement basic audio functions like play, stop and pause. I have stuffed all the code inside onCreate method. Is this best practise to follow?

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {  
        Button start,pause,stop;  
        @Override  
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {  
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);  

            start=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);  
            pause=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);  
            stop=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button3);  
            //creating media player  
            final MediaPlayer mp=new MediaPlayer();  
            try{  
                    //you can change the path, here path is external directory(e.g. sdcard) /Music/maine.mp3  
            mp.setDataSource(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+"/Music/maine.mp3");  

            mp.prepare();  
            }catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}  

            start.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {  
                @Override  
                public void onClick(View v) {  
                    mp.start();  
                }  
            });  
            pause.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {  
                @Override  
                public void onClick(View v) {  
                    mp.pause();  
                }  
            });  
            stop.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {  
                @Override  
                public void onClick(View v) {  
                    mp.stop();  
                }  
            });  
        }  
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could let your class implement `OnClickListener`

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{
    ...
}
```

and then use the `onClick`function like this:

```
public void onClick(View v)
{
    switch (v.getId())
    {
        case R.id.button1:
            mp.start();  
            break;
        case R.id.button2:
            mp.pause();  
            break;
        case R.id.button3:
            mp.stop();  
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

That way you have all actions that happen on a press of a button in the same place in your program.

You should also change the ID to something more meaningful, eg. `play`, `pause`, `stop`.
This makes your code far more maintainable and easier to understand which `Button` does what just by skimming the code of the `MainActivity`(which you also might want to rename to something like `MediaPlayerActivity` incase you decide to add additional `Activity` classes, for example to select a new song.

Additionally I would advise you to change the visibility of the `Button`s to private, rather than default.

Comment: via your solution if we change button to image then also no need for refactoring of code is required ! ! Thanks for the review, much appreciated

Answer (score 4):

Not only can you have your class implement the interface, but you can also use an `onClick` property in your XML. See [onClick in XML vs. onClickListener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21319996/android-onclick-in-xml-vs-onclicklistener)

In onCreate:

```
start = (Button) findViewById(R.id.startButton);
```

New method in your class:

```
public void startButtonPress(View view) {
    mp.start();
}
```

In your XML:

```
<button .... onClick="startButtonPress" />
```

---

Additionally, you should look over your indentation and spacing.

This part of your code:

```
        try{  
                //you can change the path, here path is external directory(e.g. sdcard) /Music/maine.mp3  
        mp.setDataSource(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+"/Music/maine.mp3");  

        mp.prepare();  
        }catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
```

Is more readable as:

```
        try {  
            // you can change the path, here path is external directory(e.g. sdcard) /Music/maine.mp3
            mp.setDataSource(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/Music/maine.mp3");  
            mp.prepare();  
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

---

Additionally:

- Think about the users of your app, do all of them have a `/Music/maine.mp3` file? No. I don't know what your main goal with this app is though, but playing only one specific file that has to be at a certain place hopefully isn't it.
- Again, think about the users, can they read the output from `e.printStackTrace();` with `adb logcat`? No. I'd recommend showing a `Toast` or a `Dialog` there as well.

Comment: If we try to handle via xml only then I don't think there is any need for this "start = (Button) findViewById(R.id.startButton);" line of code. As i have read that performance wise both the approaches are same so what could be real advantages of each approach i.e handle click event via xml or through java code only ?

Comment: @AnkitGarg The only benefit is that you'll have less code in the constructor.